# Invalid type in dll <dllname.dll><functionname> but I don't see the error

Tags: c++, dll, capl, canoe

```
CAPL_DLL_INFO4 table[] = {
{CDLL_VERSION_NAME, (CAPL_FARCALL)CDLL_VERSION, "", "", CAPL_DLL_CDECL, 0xabcd, CDLL_EXPORT },

  ... 
  {"dllTEST",(CAPL_FARCALL)GetAttribute,"CAPL_DLL","...",'I', 5, "IIICI", "\001\001\001\100\001",{ "x","x","x","x","x" } },
  ...

{0, 0}
};
CAPLEXPORT CAPL_DLL_INFO4 far * caplDllTable4 = table;
```

This is my CAPL Export Table in the sourcefile, which is written in c++ and compiles without errors or warnings to a *.dll. The function interface looks like this in my definition and prototype:

```
int CAPLEXPORT far CAPLPASCAL GetAttribute(int16 a, int16 b, int16 c, char d[], int16 e);
```

After successfully implementing the *.dll into CANoe, I get the compile error in CANoe:

```
CAPL node 'ECU 1': Compilation of '..\ecu.can' failed with error(s)
Invalid type in DLL ..\abc.dll, function dllTEST.
```

Am I missing something obvious? The used types in the function are all finely casted to CAPL conform types, in [this](http://vector.com/portal/medien/cmc/application_notes/AN-AND-1-158_Implementing_and_Integrating_CAPL_DLLs.pdf) pdf on page 15 you can read about the error:

> This error is caught while compiling a CAPL program. The function defined in the CAPL Export Table is incorrect. Most of the time it is the parameter settings in the CAPL Export Table.

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Visual C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ["Implementing and Integrating CAPL DLLs"](http://vector.com/portal/medien/cmc/application_notes/AN-AND-1-158_Implementing_and_Integrating_CAPL_DLLs.pdf) manual, your function declaration and the function table should look something like this:

```
long CAPLEXPORT far CAPLPASCAL GetAttribute(long a, long b, long c, char d[], long e);

CAPL_DLL_INFO table[] = {
    {CDLL_VERSION_NAME, (CAPL_FARCALL)CDLL_VERSION, CAPL_DLL_CDECL, 0xabcd, CDLL_EXPORT},
    ... 
    {"dllTEST", (CAPL_FARCALL)GetAttribute, 'L', 5, "LLLCL", "\000\000\000\001\000"},
    ...
    {0, 0}
};

unsigned long CAPLEXPORT __cdecl caplDllGetTable(void)
{
    return (unsigned long)table;
}
```

#### Explanation

1. Since only the 4-th parameter (`d`) is an array (1-dimensional), the **Array Depth Definition** is:

   ```
   "\000\000\000\001\000"
   ```
2. Do not use `int16`. Use the types described in Table 3 (**Function Parameter And Return Value Data Types**). Since `int` and `char` can only be used if array size !=0, we are using `long`.